# I received this error message: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [15573, 15600]. How do I resolve it please?

Tags: python

[image: Screenshot of codes][Data source](https://www.kaggle.com/c/fake-news/data)

I received that error and when running my code, I realised that the issue lies with my `X_train` and `y_train`.

The link below is the source of my data (test.csv and train.csv)

My `X_train.shape` gave me (15573,) and my `y_train` gave me (15600,)

How do I reshape this?

Comment: You cat reshap them, you have to figure why it's happening because y_train and X_train will have same shape by default

Comment: @Aditya Strangely, my X_test and y_test tally...Is there a particular reason why it isn't the same for y_train and X_train?

Comment: See if you are dropping some rows or not or else if they are one-to-one matching, then just reduce the X_train;

Comment: @Aditya Got it, will give that a shot! To reduce the X_train, I inputted this code: y_train_new=y_train[1:17644] but it showed me an error. The aim is to make it the same as that of y_train

Comment: 17644 isn't the y_train dims, it's 15600 but be careful, you shouldn't be using such tricks as in a normal scenario, this shouldn't happen actually. If you can share your preprocessing, folks can then help finding what's causing it unless it's by default like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely get problems because you remove rows containing nulls in `X_train` and `y_train` independent of each other. `y_train` probably has few, or no nulls and `X_train` probably has some. So when you remove a row in `X_train` and the same row is not removed in `y_train` it will cause your data to be unsynced and have different lenghts. Instead you should remove nulls before you separate X and y.

Before this:

```
X = df['text']
y = df['label']
```

Do this:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

And remove this:

```
X_train.dropna(inplace=True)
X_test.dropna(inplace=True)
y_train.dropna(inplace=True)
y_test.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you :)